# Two way data binding in AngularJS Directives

Tags: javascript, data-binding, frameworks, angularjs

I have been trying to define directives so I can display different "widgets" in a form, depending on the type of field and its parameters, which are stored in a database. I need to react to different types of scenarios, hence the need for directives to handle layout.

While playing with a few examples, I came up with a code that *kinda* works:

### HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" style="width: 90%"/>  
<div class="zippy" zippy-title="myModel"></div>
```

### Directive

```
myApp.directive('zippy', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      // This HTML will replace the zippy directive.
      transclude: true,
      scope: { title:'=zippyTitle' },
      template: '<input type="text" value="{{title}}"style="width: 90%"/>',
      // The linking function will add behavior to the template
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Title element
            element.bind('blur keyup change', function() {
                scope.$apply(read);
            });

            var input = element.children();


            function read() {
                scope.title = input.val();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This seems to works (albeit noticeably slower than a *proper* angularJS variable binding) but I figure there must be a better way to do this. Can anyone shed some light on the matter?

Comment: Just curious, I know you didn't end up needing to call $apply manually, but why were you binding both `blur` and `change`? Isn't that redundant? If not, I'd be curious to know what the difference is from just using `keyup blur`.

Comment: `blur` and `change` are different, but I believe for practical purposes, `keyup` and `change` are functionally similar. The only diference would be that if I changed the input's value programmatically, using `change` would trigger an event (the input's data changing), whereas leaving `change` out would make such a change invisible, unless it came from a keystroke. Bear in mind this was "ages" ago, I had no idea what I was doing with the awesome beast that is angularJS ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know why you are triggering the `$apply` method manually because you actually don't need it.

I edited the example you used from the Angular page and included the input.
It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6HcGS/2/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="zippyModule">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
    Title: <input ng-model="title">
    <hr>
    <div class="zippy" zippy-title="title"></div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
function Ctrl3($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Lorem Ipsum';
}

angular.module('zippyModule', [])
  .directive('zippy', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: { title:'=zippyTitle' },
      template: '<input type="text" value="{{title}}"style="width: 90%"/>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // Your controller
      }
    }
  });
```

**UPDATE**
maxisam is right, you have to use `ng-model` instead of binding the variable against the value like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title" style="width: 90%"/>
```

Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/6HcGS/3/

Comment: It doesn't, it works one way only (as is in the angular docs' examples). What I'm atempting is a two way data-binding scenario - change the $scope value and the directive's value updates, change the directive's value and the $scope value updates. LUCKY NOTE - Brian Ford from the angularJS team kinda answers this, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=8_7K6bud5kw

Comment: @TiagoRoldão maxisam is right, I just updated my post and the jsfiddle

Comment: Great! The keyword "title" is confusing though.. Could you update your fiddle renaming "title" to something like "innerTitle", so that the binding between an inner and an outer variable (in a directive) is clear?

Answer (score 11):

You mean something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/QpUdA/)** ?

I basically use @Flek's example.
The only difference being `ng-model='title'`

The trick to doing two-way binding is ng-model, and it states in the [document](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel):

> **ngModel is directive that tells Angular to do two-way data binding.**
>   It works together with input, select, textarea. You can easily write
>   your own directives to use ngModel as well.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title" style="width: 90%"/>
```

Comment: You are right thank! :) I updated my post and included the corrected jsfiddle!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to pass to a callback parameter in a directive. The controller template:

```
    <component-paging-select-directive
            page-item-limit="{{pageItemLimit}}"
            page-change-handler="pageChangeHandler(paramPulledOutOffThinAir)"
            ></component-paging-select-directive>
```

The directive:

```
angular.module('component')
    .directive('componentPagingSelectDirective', [
        function( ) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: { 
                    // using the '=' for two way doesn't work
                    pageItemLimit:  '@', // the '@' is one way from controller
                    pageChangeHandler: '&'
                },
                controller: function($scope) {   
                    // pass value from this scope to controller method. 
                    // controller method will update the var in controller scope
                    $scope.pageChangeHandler({
                        paramPulledOutOffThinAir: $scope.pageItemLimit
                    })

                }, ...
```

In the controller:

```
angular.module('...').controller(...
        $scope.pageItemLimit = 0; // initial value for controller scoped var

        // complete the data update by setting the var in controller scope 
        // to the one from the directive
        $scope.pageChangeHandler = function(paramPulledOutOffThinAir) {
            $scope.pageItemLimit = paramPulledOutOffThinAir;
        }
```

Note the difference in function parameters for the directive (an object with parameter as keys), template ('unwrapped' keys from the parameter object in directive), and controller definition.