# How can I apply a CSS style to an ng-repeat element inside a directive, based on $scope.$watch on it's attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

My View Code:

```
<div ng-repeat = "i in items track by $index">
   <myDirective label = "i.labels"> </myDirective>
</div>
```

Parts of the directive code:

```
return {
  scope : {
    label : '='
  }
  link : function($scope, elem, attrs){
     $scope.$watch('label', function(v){
        if(v[1] == "somevalue"){ // apply a css style to this ng-repeat item.}
     });
  }

}
```

I want to apply a css style to the current element based on `v[1]`. What's the "angular way" of achieving this ***inside a directive***?

Comment: Take a look here for databinding in a directive **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294507/two-way-data-binding-in-angularjs-directives**, just use style and not value

Comment: @Johnny000 : Is there something wrong with the way I'm achieving data-binding above?

Comment: I don't know why you want to use watch, but if you don't really need to, try to avoid using $watch as it's not good for the performance **http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/removing-the-unneeded-watches/**

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change the style from within the directive in your example. You could simply do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items track by $index" 
     ng-style="{ background: i.labels[1] == 'somevalue' ? 'red' : 'blue' }">
   <myDirective label="i.labels"></myDirective>
</div>
```

But if you really want to change the style from the directive, then in my opinion you should put the outer div inside of the directive's view. That way, you can manipulate it easily.

Comment: Does angular expressions support ternary operations?

Comment: they don't, you have to do i.labels[1] == 'somevalue' && 'red' || 'blue'

Comment: They do since Angular 1.1.5.

Comment: @AlonGubkin, I'm aware of this technique. My question was specific to angular directives. Thanks never the less.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the directive you can use `jqLite` selectors for finding parent `ng-repeat` div. Then you can apply a specific class if the desired condition is met.

I have created following sample app.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    labels: ["red", "black"]
  }, {
    labels: ["faint-green", "green"]
  }, {
    labels: ["pink", "orange"]
  }, {
    labels: ["USA"]
  }];
}).directive('mydirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      label: '='
    },

    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
      $scope.repeatingElem = $(elem).parent('div[ng-repeat]');
      $scope.$watch('label', function(v) {

        if (v[1] == "green") {
          // apply a css class to ng-repeat element.
          $scope.repeatingElem.addClass('bg-success');
        }

      });
    }
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="i in items">
    <mydirective label="i.labels"></mydirective> {{i.labels}}
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**[Plnkr Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/MLF8mUwTwc5yYi4quoOh?p=preview)**